# Filtering Array for table using React JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api

I've created a date filter for my table that if date exist it shows that data only else it shows all data . It shows all data only even though i entered date it didn't work. I really need this community help for this. i feel exhausted working on this. please guide me ill give my sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-mendel-w4n6g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi (Vanakkam) Karthikeyan,

Thank you for sharing the codesandbox link.

The 'componentDidMount' lifecycle method does not get called each time the rsuite daterangepicker triggers onChange, based on my observation. ReactJS documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) provides more details of when the method is triggered, when it is appropriate to use it, etc.

If it is acceptable to filter the data within the 'async' handleChange method, the filtering works.

Here is one possible implementation:

```
  async handleChange(dates) {
    const dtfmt = "yyyy-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss";
    const data = await (await fetch("/data.json")).json();
    dates && dates.length > 0 ?
      (data || []).length &&
      this.setState({
        startDate: dates[0], // redundant
        endDate: dates[1], // redundant
        datefilter: data.filter(
          d => moment(d.Date, dtfmt).isBetween(
            moment(dates[0], dtfmt), moment(dates[1], dtfmt)
          )
        )
      }) :
      (data || []).length &&
      this.setState({
        startDate: '',
        endDate: '',
        datefilter: data
      });
  };
```

**Edited** the solution above to handle 'empty' dates.

And, this is how it filtered the dates:

[Screenshot of codesandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhTZo.png)

If it is mandatory to place the data-load in lifecycle methods, you may want to declare a separate 'async' method & then call that from the relevant lifecycle method/s (may be like [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) ?).

Comment: thank you so much bro it helps me a lot . after i filter data when i try to clear dates i got error like Cannot read property 'length' of null (dates.length) can you tell me why it happens?

Comment: @KarthikeyanM, thank you (nandri) bro, for accepting answer. The answer has been edited to handle empty 'dates' parameter, as well as undefined/null 'data'.

You may need to wrap the API call in try-catch for better error-handling.

Comment: bro kindly answer these please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595974/socket-create-multiple-connection-even-when-only-one-user-connected

Comment: Have reviewed that question bro. Mannikkavum (apologies), i haven't worked on sockets before.

Comment: (romba nandri) bro i'm fixed that issue